# how to use tar command with find exec and grep in linux

Tags: bash

I need to find all files with a specific string and tar them. I used the below syntax, but it's not working.

```
find . -iname '*.log' -exec grep -l 'abcdef' {} tar mytar.tar.gz -T - \;
```

And I don't want to use pipe syntax like below (for specific reasons)

```
find . -name '*.log' | xargs grep -l 'abcdef' | tar Mytar.tar.gz -T -
```

I need to use find with exec and grep each file and tar the resultant list of files.

Thanks

Comment: You are going to need to use a pipe *somewhere*, probably something like `find ... -exec sh -c 'grep ... | tar ...'`. What is your aversion to pipes?

Comment: Well -- you could certainly use two separate `-exec` clauses, one to grep the file, a second one to invoke `tar` with names for which `grep` returned an exit status of 0. But... yes, why the aversion to pipes?

Comment: I am running this in a container and it is not honouring pipes somehow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `grep -lR --null` piped to `xargs -0 tar ...` for this:

```
grep -lR --null --include='*.log' 'abcdef' . | xargs -0 tar cvzf mytar.tar.gz -T -
```

Comment: HelloI am using absolute path in my grep command (/logs/dir1/subdir1/), instead of ., and it says Removing leading / from member names. When I tried with tar -P --absolute-names cvzf Mytar.tar.gz, it says: You must specify one of the -Acstrux or --test-label options. I am still trying to find a solution

Comment: You can do: `cd /logs/dir1/subdir1/; grep -lR --null --include='*.log' 'abcdef' . | xargs -0 tar cvzf mytar.tar.gz -T -`

Answer (score 2):

`Process substitution` comes to rescue if you hate pipes:

```
tar -czf mytar.tar.gz -T <(find . -type f -iname '*.log' -exec grep -l 'abcdef' {} +)
```